# Change content in a Dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to generate the same functionality that www.inkling.com has when you click on the "Sign Up or Log In" link and then the "question mark" (which is for resetting your password)...I think they implemented theirs with a dialog box whose content can change based on the user's selection.

Any help with be appreciated!

Taiwo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have two divs both hidden. When you click on the link show one, if you then click on the question mark, hide that one, then show the other...

Here's a fiddle to illustrate - http://jsfiddle.net/Dj8xG/

**jquery**

```
$('#signup').click(function(){
    $('#login').show();
});

$('#forgot').click(function(){
    $('#login').hide();
    $('#reset').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know some CSS, you should have this basic structure:

```
<div id="float_content" style="position:absolute">
    <div id="login">
        <a href="#" class="first_mark">?</a>        
    </div>

    <div id="forgot" style="display:none">
        <a href="#" class="second_mark">?</a>   
    </div>
</div>
```

first you have to receive the main div "float_content" and then play with the show() hide() to the inner divs

```
$(".first_mark").live('click', function(e)
       {
                e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("div").hide();
                $("#forgot").show();
    });


$(".second_mark").live('click', function(e)
       {
                e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("div").hide();
                $("#login").show();
    });
```